# How to get the IP address of the author post in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have installed an iThemes security plugin on my wordpress website in order to secure my site. Also, I have installed a **WP Statistics** in order to view the IP addresses of the visitors. But, this plugin does not record the IP address of an author who created a post. I've been searching on the web for a PHP script or a SQL query to get the said IP address.

Does anybody know how to get the IP address of an author using PHP script or SQL query?

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_client_ip() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    return $ipaddress;
}
```

This would be helpful, you just need to insert this into posting script and then just push it to base like normal variable.

Comment: Thanks for the script, but I am trying to view the IP address of author based on post_id of wordpress.. ,.  The author already published a post on my website and I don't know the IP address where he created the post..

Comment: If plugin don't record IP before post of user you can't get it, because theres no record to view.

Comment: Bearing in mind this isn't codereview, that code could be simplified like: `function get_client_ip() { 
 $keys = array('HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED' /*, etc...*/); 
 foreach($keys as $key) { 
  if (isset($_SERVER[$key]) { 
   return $_SERVER[$key]; 
  }  
 } 
 return 'UNKNOWN'; 
}`